# Calculating rate of renewal for Certificate of Deposit

Tags: regression

I am trying to calculate the rate of renewal for a large stock of Certificates of Deposit. These contracts are given on a fixed amount of time and some of them get renewed every time they reach maturity.

I thought one way I could model the situation was taking the percentage of renewal every day and then making a regression to project that number but I think its not robust enough.